# How do I submit variables from Android Activity to website url?

Tags: java, android, http-post, httpurlconnection

I have an application built that works like a form, it takes four fields and validates the information in order to make sure that no invalid characters are entered. These four fields are stored in variables:

- Phone
- Name
- Email
- Comments

  Now I want to submit  the form data (whatever is entered into these four fields and stored to the variables) to a url (will use http://www.test.com), but I am not sure how to go about doing this. I think I am looking for something called the HttpURLConnection, but I am not sure how to specify which variable is sent. The code below I found from the website http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

  ```
  private class UploadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long>{
  protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {

      try {
          HttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient();
          HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.test.com");

          List<NameValuePair> data = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
          data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", "value"));
          data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "value"));
          data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "value"));
          data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("comments", "value"));
          post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));

          HttpResponse response = http.execute(post);
          // do something with the response
      }
      catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
          // do something
          finish();
      }
      catch (IOException e) {
          // do something
          finish();
      }
  ```

  }

  }

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Does web-site accepts value in Parameter-value pair, I mean in Url rewritting?

Comment: What does the server expect ? A POST request ? A GET request with parameters in the query string ?

Comment: I believe the server expects a POST request

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to send form data to a server is to use HttpClient, and HttpPost.

Try something like this:

```
try {
    HttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost   post = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com/process");

    List<NameValuePair> data = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", "value");
    data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "value");
    data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "value");
    data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("comments", "value");
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));

    HttpResponse response = http.execute(post);
    // do something with the response
}
catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // do something
}
catch (IOException e) {
    // do something
}
```

Note, you'll want to perform this operation in an AsyncTask so you don't lock up the UI thread waiting for the networking operations to complete.

**Edit**

Here's a simple quick example of what it might look like in an AsyncTask.

```
public class SendTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    String responseString;

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

            HttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.test.com");

            List<NameValuePair> data = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", "value"));
            data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "value"));
            data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "value"));
            data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("comments", "value"));
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));

            HttpResponse response = http.execute(post);
            responseString = new BasicResponseHandler().
                                 handleResponse(response); // Basic handler
            return true;
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // do something useful to recover from the exception
            // Note: there may not be anything useful to do here
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // do something useful to recover from the exception
            // Note: there may not be anything useful to do here
        }           
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
        // TODO: Do something more useful here
        if (success) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success: " + responseString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, simple example. Though it should be mentioned you should generally use a ResponseHandler to handle HTTP responses -- this ensures the entity is always consumed and the connection is properly released.

Comment: @nEx.Software thank you for your example, this definitely clears some things up. But I do have some questions, what do the two catch statements do, and how do you perform this operation in an AsyncTask? Do I just extend AsyncTask on the class where I am using this?

Comment: The two catch statements are required as HttpClient.execute(...) can throw these exceptions. I doubt you'd ever hit the ClientProtocolException, but you may hit the IOException if connectivity cannot be established. As far as using an AsyncTask with this, create an inner class (or even an anonymous class) which extends AsyncTask and use the method above in the doInBackground method.

Comment: @nEx.Software I updated my code above, but I don't think I have it yet. Can you help me through what you think is wrong with the code above? Thank you

Comment: Well, that depends. The only thing I would technically consider "wrong" about the new code is the finish() call in the catch. You also can change it to `extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {` if you aren't sending in any parameters, updating progress, or returning any results. I've added one example of how you might approach it.

Comment: @nEx.Software Oh ok, I thought something HAD to be done with those two catch statements. Last question, this may be a dumb one. How do I call the method to actually upload? When I put SendTask(); under the onClick method, I get an undefined method message.

Comment: @nEx.Software Thank you so much for all of your help! This was a great learning experience =]

Comment: Some tips for newbies copy and pasting this code:
`SendTask` needs to be an inner class in your `MainActivity` for the Toasts to work.
You can't use a generic `OnClickListener` or your `MainActivity` won't be in scope. Have your fragment implement `View.OnClickListener`.
You need to set `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in `AndroidManifest.XML`.

Answer (score 1):

Add the fields to the url as parameters.

```
String phone="phone=234432";
String name="name=John Smith";
String email="email=test@email.com"; 

Url = new URL("http://www.test.com?"+phone+"&"+name+"&"+email);
```

Not tested, but it should work in a GET Http request.

Comment: I'm a little confused, how does this send the data to the url that's specified?

Answer (score 0):

//using xml request

```
String url="http://www.test.com";
String xmlRequest="<message xmlns=\"http://test.com/schemas/ma\"><header></header>"+
"<body><phone>9944556622</phone><name>Mytest name</name><email>mytest@email.com</email>"+"<comments>hay this seems nice</comments></body></message>"

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(xmlRequest,HTTP.UTF_8);


httppost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/xml");
httppost.setHeader("Accept","application/xml");

httppost.setEntity(se);

BasicHttpResponse httpResponse = (BasicHttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httppost);

   StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();
```

Comment: thank you for the response. Can you walk through and explain to me what you are doing? Can I replace the static text in the xml with a variable?

Comment: actually you need the api reference i.e how to send the request and get the response from your server.

Comment: if you have an api you need to try it first in REST Client. if it succeeds directly you can do it in your program.

Answer (score 0):

```
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    Log.i("sampath","line 139");
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                    BasicNameValuePair usernameBasicNameValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("textMessage", msg);

                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    nameValuePairList.add(usernameBasicNameValuePair);

                    try {

                        UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairList);


                        httpPost.setEntity(urlEncodedFormEntity);

                        try {

                            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);


                            InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

                            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

                            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

                            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                            String bufferedStrChunk = null;

                            while((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                                stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
                            }

                            return stringBuilder.toString();

                        } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
                            System.out.println("Firstption caz of HttpResponese :" + cpe);
                            cpe.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException ioe) {
                            System.out.println("Secondption caz of HttpResponse :" + ioe);
                            ioe.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                        System.out.println("Anption given because of UrlEncodedFormEntity argument :" + uee);
                        uee.printStackTrace();
                    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Here is the php file

<?php
$message = $_POST['textMessage'];
echo 'working fine'.$message;
$filename="androidmessages.html";
file_put_contents($filename,"Entered Text is:".$message."<br />",FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

Comment: make sure you create androidmessages.html in the same directory where the php file resides