# Pass Data from Android Java to Webview - jQueryMobile

Tags: java, android, html, jquery-mobile, android-webview

I followed the trick for passing data to HTML webview from SO post [How to pass parameter into HTML file from android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626991/how-to-pass-parameter-into-html-file-from-android).

I have this in my Java:

```
try {
    String template = streamToString(getAssets().open("html/index.html"));
    String data = template.replaceAll("%PARAMETER%", PARAMETER);

    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/html/", data, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In my HTML, I have the string `"%PARAMETER%"`.

The solution works for my test device running Android 2.3.6, but didn't work in device running Android 4.1.1. The HTML have some CSS and JS files. Is the problem related to the content of the HTML page?

Any better approach on what I'm trying to achieve? Simple I just want to send data from Java to HTML webview.

This is the content of HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>

    <title>Like a Pub</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $('#index-page').live('pageshow', function(event, data){
            //
        });
    </script>


</head>

<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="index-page">
        %WEBSITE_URL%
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `but didn't work in device running Android 4.1.1` what didn't work about it on the 4.1.1 device? The parameter didn't get replaced? the app force closed? try using `webView.loadData(data, "text/html", "utf-8")`.

Comment: the string was replaced. I saw it in logcat. But the html/data was not loaded.

Comment: `webView.loadData` didn't work. The problem with `loadData` are the JS and other related files.

Comment: are you using `setJavascriptEnabled(true);` ?

Comment: yes, javascript was enabled already.

Comment: If you don't do the string replacement does the html load correctly on 4.1.1?

Comment: i tried to log the string replaced, no problem on string.

Comment: but does it display in the webview if you don't replace the strings? If not then you can rule out that is anything related to the actual replacement that is the issue.